# Como conectar y desconectar altavoz Bluetooth en DELPHI

Tags: delphi, bluetooth

En Delphi, tengo claro como

Buscar dispositivos, emparejarlos, ver los emparejados y desemparejarlos.
También es sencillo, conectar con una impresora Bluetooth y por socket mandarle cosas a imprimir.
Pero no encuentro nada sobre lo siguiente

Una cosa es ver los dispositivos emparejados y otra los conectados.
Centrándonos en los altavoces. Tengo tres dispositivos emparejados

ALTAVOZ1
Emparejado

ALTAVOZ2
Emparejado

ALTAVOZ3
Música Conectada

y el sonido se escucha por el ALTAVOZ3

Quiero poder desde Delphi, cambiar y que en vez de ser ALTAVOZ3 el que tenga 'Música conectada' sea ALTAVOZ2 por ejemplo.
Yo puedo cargar en un TMEMO los dispositivos Emparejados y me saldrá
ALTAVOZ1
ALTAVOZ2
ALTAVOZ3

Pero quiero saber cual de los tres está en modo 'Musica Conectada' y cómo puedo cambiarlo.

Gracias

```
    uses
     System.Bluetooth, System.Bluetooth.Components, System.Classes, 
     System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs, System.UITypes;

    Var
    FSocket: TBluetoothSocket;
    FBluetoothManager: TBluetoothManager;
    FDiscoverDevices: TBluetoothDeviceList;
    FPairedDevices: TBluetoothDeviceList;
    FAdapter: TBluetoothAdapter;
// Inicializa Componentes y devuelve la lista de dispositivos
procedure Conectar(Var Device1: TStringList; Var Res: Boolean);
begin
   Device1:= TStringList.Create;
    FBluetoothManager := TBluetoothManager.Current;
    FAdapter := FBluetoothManager.CurrentAdapter;
    if ManagerConnected then Begin
      PairedDevices(Device1);
      Res:= True;
    End;
end;
// Buscar Dsipositivos emparejados
procedure PairedDevices(Var Device2: TStringList);
var I: Integer;
begin
  Device2:= TStringList.Create;
  if ManagerConnected then begin
    FPairedDevices := FBluetoothManager.GetPairedDevices;
    if FPairedDevices.Count > 0 then for I:= 0 to FPairedDevices.Count - 1 
  do  Device2.Add(FPairedDevices[I].DeviceName)
      else Device2.Add('No Paired Devices');
  End else Device2.Add('No Paired Devices');
end;
// Comprueba si esta activo el Bluetooh
function ManagerConnected:Boolean;
begin
    FBluetoothManager := TBluetoothManager.Current;
    FAdapter := FBluetoothManager.CurrentAdapter;
  if FBluetoothManager.ConnectionState = 
 TBluetoothConnectionState.Connected then Result := True else Result:= 
False;
end;
{ Esta funcion es la que curiosamente me conecta el dispositivo y lo hace, a pesar de que FSocket.Connect da error. Pero luego no tengo ningún control para poder desconectar y conectarme a otro dispositivo.
Los servicios que tiene son
 A2DP SNK Service
 A2DP SRC Service
 A/V Remote Control
 A/V Remote Control Target
y activo el FSocket dando la UUID del primer servicio
} 
function ConnectDisp(ANomeDevice: String): Boolean;
Var lDevice: TBluetoothDevice;
    LServices: TBluetoothServiceList;
    Estado: TBluetoothDeviceState;
    i: Integer; Dv: Boolean;
begin
    Result := False;
    lDevice := ObtenerDevice(ANomeDevice);
    if (Assigned(LDevice)) then Begin
      if NOT (Assigned(FSocket)) then Begin
        LServices := LDevice.GetServices;
        FSocket := LDevice.CreateClientSocket(LServices[0].UUID, True);
      End;
      Try
        FSocket.Connect;
      Except

      End;
    End;
end;
// Esta función realmente no hace nada. No funciona
Function DesConnectDisp: Boolean;
Begin
    if (Assigned(FSocket)) then Begin
      FreeAndNil(FSocket);
    //  FSocket.Close;

    End;
End;
// Requerido por ConectarImpresora
function ObtenerDevice(ANomeDevice: String): TBluetoothDevice;
var
  lDevice: TBluetoothDevice;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for lDevice in FBluetoothManager.GetPairedDevices do if lDevice.DeviceName = ANomeDevice then Result := lDevice;
end;
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo que hayas realizados. tu pregunta me parece que es muy grande y deberias acotarla.

Answer (score 1):

En esta dirección

https://itectec.com/superuser/scripting-connecting-disconnecting-a-paired-bluetooth-device/

está la solución en el programa btcom.exe.

El tratamiento más o menos es:

```
Uses  System.Bluetooth, ShellApi, Winapi.Messages, AdvPanel;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ************** Procedimiento que Escanea Dispositivos Bluetooth *************
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TForm1.DiscoveryD;
Var i: Integer;
begin
  FBluetoothManager := TBluetoothManager.Current;
  FAdapter := FBluetoothManager.CurrentAdapter;
  if FBluetoothManager.ConnectionState = TBluetoothConnectionState.Connected then Begin
    FPairedDevices := FBluetoothManager.GetPairedDevices;
  end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ************** Gestion de la selección de elementos *************************
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TForm1.b01click(Sender: TObject);
Var i, n, w: Integer; iUID: String;
begin
 If BotonAltavoz.Down Then Begin
    i := (Sender as TAdvPanel).Tag;
    if FBluetoothManager.ConnectionState = TBluetoothConnectionState.Connected  then Begin
      iUID:= FPairedDevices[i].Address;
      n:= 0;
      if (Sender As TAdvPanel).ColorTo = BotonCogido then Begin  // BotonCogido esta en verde que significa que está activo
        EjecutaExterno(iUID, '110B', '-r'); // Desactivo los servicios
        EjecutaExterno(iUID, '110E', '-r');
        DiscoveryD; // Al parar los servicios, debo volver a leer los dispositivos emparejados, ya que cambia el orden
        w:= Damei(iUID);
        while (FPairedDevices[w].State = TBluetoothDeviceState.Connected) AND (n < 15) do begin
         Sleep(2000);
         DiscoveryD;
         w:= Damei(iUID);
         Inc(n);
        end;
      End Else Begin // Si el color no es BotonCogido Activo los servicios
        EjecutaExterno(iUID, '110E', '-c');
        EjecutaExterno(iUID, '110B', '-c');
        DiscoveryD;
        w:= Damei(iUID);
        while (FPairedDevices[w].State = TBluetoothDeviceState.Paired) AND (n < 15) do begin
         Sleep(2000);
         DiscoveryD;
         w:= Damei(iUID);
         Inc(n);
        end;
End;

      if NOT (N < 15) then Begin
        PanelMensaje.Caption:= '***** ERROR GESTIONANDO BLUETOOTH *****';
        Sleep(5000);
      End;
End;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ************** Ejecuta BTCOM para gestionar el BLUETOOTH ********************
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TForm1.EjecutaExterno(DEVICE_ADDRESS, SERVICE_UUID, BTCOM_TIPE: STring);
var h: HWND; Folder, Comando, Parametros: String;
begin
    Folder := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
    Comando:= 'BtCom.exe';
    Parametros:= BTCOM_TIPE + ' -b"' + DEVICE_ADDRESS + '" -s' + SERVICE_UUID;
    ShellExecute(Handle, 'Open', PWideChar(Comando), PWideChar(Parametros), PWideChar(Folder), SW_HIDE);
    sleep(3000);
    h := FindWindow(nil, 'BtCom'); // Hago un bucle esperando que termine el programa Btcom
    while h <> 0 do Begin
      Sleep(3000);
      h := FindWindow(nil, 'BtCom');
    End;
end;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ************** Calcula el componente BLUETOOTH según su dirección MAC *******
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function  TForm1.Damei(Id: String): Integer;
VAr i: Integer;
Begin
  Result:= -1;
  for I := 0 to FPairedDevices.Count -1 do Begin
    if FPairedDevices.Items[i].address = Id then Begin
      Result:= I;
      Exit;
    End;
  End;
End;
```

Y esto me permite conectar y desconectar los diferentes altavoces inalámbricos que tengo emparejados. En

```
i := (Sender as TAdvPanel).Tag;
```

`TAdvPanel` corresponde a un componente de TMSSoftware.